# C++ scope resolution usage with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope

I have recently stumbled across two different ways to represent variables from a base class in a derived class.  I know that this is a subjective matter, but I would like to hear arguments for/against the two different forms of syntax listed below...

Version 1:

```
// in some code in the derived class...
base_class_member_variable_ = 0xBEEF;
```

Version 2:

```
// in some code in the derived class...
MyBaseClass::base_class_member_variable_ = 0xBEEF;
```

Also, an extension of Version 2, when the base class is in a different namespace:

```
// in some code in the derived class...
base_namespace::MyBaseClass::base_class_member_variable_ = 0xBEEF;
```

I'm wondering if it makes sense to explicitly state where the variable is coming from if it isn't declared/defined in the derived class.  Either version compiles, so we're only talking about style here.

I understand that this topic is highly subjective.  However, I am really trying to improve my coding practice, without any access in my current position to senior-level engineers with C++ experience.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I won't venture an opinion, but in general to help you learn how to improve your code, I would recommend reading Bruce Eckel's 2 volumes titled "Thinking in C++". They can be bought from book sellers, and are **also available FREE to download** on Bruce's website: http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I'll be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the extra scoping stuff is just being explicit about what the compiler is able to infer anyway. So unless there's a particularly ambiguous case, there no need to put all that scoping stuff on there.

As for what's best in terms of style and helps others to understand the code better... I'm going to avoid that because it comes dangerously close to rendering an unsupportable opinion. However, I will say that what I've commonly seen is 1) people don't use more scoping modifiers than necessary to remove ambiguity, and 2) people do often have coding standards (such as naming conventions) for how member variables are referred to. For example, they may start all member variables with the prefix "m_", or they may use "this->" every time they refer to a member variable. Of course not everyone does things this way, but it's what seems to me to be relatively common practice.

That said, if you're working on your own then you can do whatever works for you. On the other hand, if you're working in a large group then you should find out what the coding style conventions are for that group and follow those.

Comment: That's really been my main problem.  I'm working on my own, so I want to develop a set of standards that I can follow that are used industry-wide.  Thus far, I've only been able to find the Google C++ style guide and have been following it.  I plan on leaving my current job in a few months, so I don't want to develop bad habits that will get me laughed out of the room at my next venture.  Thanks for your answer, however.

Comment: Note that there is one situation when `Base::m` or `this->m` is required to make the code work correctly.  When a class template inherits from a dependent type, the member accesses have to be qualified in order to mark them as dependent so they will be looked up in the object.  Otherwise, the compiler will fail to resolve the symbol.  For example: `struct foo { int m; }; template<typename B> struct bar : B { bar() { this->m=0; } }; bar<foo> b;`  If you leave out `this->`, you get an error.

Comment: @It'sPete The Google style guide is a good place to start. If you're following that, I wouldn't sweat the other details... You can reflect on your own coding and thing about what _you_ think is better or worse... but bear in mind to be flexible, so you can adapt to the coding standards of a new workplace/project whatever they may be. (e.g., Some place require Hungarian Notation and others don't use it at all - be ready to go either way on this and other style details.) I guess I'm saying, it sounds like what you want is actually not to have any habits. :)

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson That's very interesting... but it's kind of an odd case. It seems very dangerous to me to refer to `this->m` when it's dependent on the template parameter _having_ a member m. Templates suggest "stick anything in here" but in this case you can't use just anything - only things that have an `m` will work...  Is there a real use case for this kind of thing?

Comment: @DaveLillethun, yes, I've used this type of construct more than once, but they aren't exactly examples that would fit in a SO comment.  However, it's not unusual to end up imposing constraints on templates like this.  If you say `T foo(T a, T b) { return a+b; }`, you are constraining `T` to have a copy constructor and a binary `+` operator that returns something convertible to `T`.  Or, think of a template that takes a generic container; that will often require `value_type`, `iterator`, `begin()`, and `end()`.  In a template, how types are used will specify how they are constrained.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research, it looks like my questions may be a moot point.  Since I am holding myself (or at least trying to...) to the Google C++ style guide, all member variables should be private anyways.  As a result, none of the above examples should ever exist in my code, except when perhaps accessing a constant that tied to that class.  In which case, it may make sense to explicitly state where the constant is coming from.

Thanks again for the answers and reassurance and excellent discussion.

Comment: Note that scope resolution doesn't just apply to member variables.  The same issues can apply to member functions or member types, both of which are routinely `public`.